# R Spec Stack level too deep (System Stack Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have three models offer_ticket, event and offer and have three their respective factories below are the models and factories are given i got error **stack level too deep**.
There is loop execute offer_ticket-to-event,  event-to-offer and then offer-to-offer_tickets 
suggest me a solution how to remove this error

> offer_Ticket

```
class Offer Ticket < Active Record::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

> event

```
class Event < Active Record::Base
   has_many     :offers , dependent: :restrict_with_error
   has_many :offer_tickets , dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

> offer

```
class Offer < Active Record::Base
   has_many :offer_tickets , dependent: :restrict_with_error
   belongs_to :event
end
```

**Their respective factories as given below**

> offer_tickets

```
Factory Girl define do
   factory :offer_ticket do
      venue_row_id        1
      sale_id             1
      status              "available"
      seat_number         1
      association(:event)
   end
end
```

> events

```
Factory Girl define do
   factory :event do |f|

      f.name { Faker::Name.name  }
      f.starts_at { Faker::Date.backward(Random.rand(20)).to_date }
      f.description { Faker::paragraph }
      after(:build) do |event|
         create(:offer, event: event)
      end
   end
 end
```

> offers

```
Factory Girl define do
  factory :offer do
    price                   1
    proxy                   1
    multiple                1
    cancel-others            1
    after(:build) do |offer|
       create(:offer_ticket, offer: offer)
    end
    association(:event)
  end
```

end

Comment: Can you add the rspec which is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for this could be the dependency between your factories.

Suppose, you want to create an `Event` using factory-girl with the factories mentioned in the question. Doing `FactoryGirl.create(:event)` will try to create `Offer` (See `:after_build` of event factory) and ...

Creation of this offer will trigger `:after_build` of offer factory, where it would try to create `OfferTicket` ...

And in offer_ticket factory, it has defined an `association :event`, which will again try to create an `Event`. Hence, this will cause an **infinite loop**.

My suggestion would be to **NOT** use `after_build` to create new objects in your case. You can create them separately and then assign then to parent object. If you provide some rspec code, it might improve my answer.

Comment: In offer_ticket_spec t try to run this piece of code 
offer_ticket = FactoryGirl.create(:offer_ticket)

Comment: Can you suggest me piece of code how to create them separately and then assign then to parent object

Comment: Just remove the `after :build` callbacks from factory and create `Event` separately using `FactoryGirl.create(:event)`. Then assign this event object to `offer_ticket` as `offer_ticket.event = event`.